# Giant meringue French pastry - what are these called?

Tags: pastry, french-cuisine, meringue

A few months ago we were visiting Paris, and in Montmartre, there were several pastry shoppes with large meringues. And by large, I mean the size of someone's head, or an American football. They were usually swirled with a pastel food coloring to give them a frosted look. But otherwise, they were just a gigantic meringue.

For the life of me, I can't find what these pastries are called. It came to a head this morning when I made a recipe which left me with 18 egg whites, and I'd love to try making them. So, does anyone have any idea what these large meringues are called??

Comment: Its sounds somewhat like a Pavlova, but that is Australian.  Do you have a picture?   For whatever it is worth, angel food cake is my standard use up egg whites recipe.

Comment: Sadly we don't have any photos - we didn't have any cameras with us, and even if we did, we were cautioned against bringing them into Montmartre because of pickpockets, lol. This is the closest I've been able to find, but it still isn't quite right (they're about 4x the size of the ones in the photo):
http://debsravingrecipes.blogspot.com/2012/12/giant-chocolate-meringues.html

Comment: Like this? http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_of9NPGo1g1M/Rarv4t5Af4I/AAAAAAAAAEM/P4CRnQWzjZI/s1600-h/IMG_1478.JPG

Answer (score 4):

They're just called meringues... Make sure to use a recipe for French meringue, not Italian meringue.

http://hipparis.com/2011/03/14/au-merveilleux-de-fred-a-meringue-bakery-in-paris/#more-16159

Answer (score 1):

I saw them in a patisserie in Bergerac called Rocaille but can't find a specific recipe . They were 3 different flavours